# After recording with mixmonitor, run the AGI script and POST the wav to another server via CURL

Tags: asterisk

I want to start an AGI script after transferring a phone call with Asterisk and recording it with mixmonitor, and POST the wav to another server via CURL, but the extensions.conf I created does not work.

```
exten => 0123456,1,MixMonitor(${UNIQUEID}.wav49)
exten => 0123456,n,Dial(SIP/xxxxxxxx@0123456,60)
exten => h,1,AGI(curl_post.php)
```

I can start curl_post.php with AGI, but the wav file is not ready yet, and I cannot do CURLPOST. How can I wait for the wav file to be created so I can CURLPOST to another server? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MixMonitor has internal option for that

```
MixMonitor(filename.extension,[options,[command]])
...
command - Will be executed when the recording is over.
Any strings matching ^{X} will be unescaped to X.
All variables will be evaluated at the time MixMonitor is called.
```

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Application_MixMonitor

For example, in FreePBX it is like this:

```
exten => 0123456,1,MixMonitor(${UNIQUEID}.wav49,,/bin/emailrecording.sh ^{CALLFILENAME})
```

https://community.freepbx.org/t/solved-how-to-email-call-recordings-post-call-recording-script/26747/18

Comment: Thank you very much. I read the link but didn't understand it. Do I just put the bash command here?

Comment: yes, you have put command as THIRD parameter.